# Unable to include UTF-8 character as value for a column in Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a list of key value pairs of "ID" and "Symbols" in to a Dataframe of two columns ["id","value"].Sample list is as given below with 4 values.(Spark session is defined as "spark")

```
L=[(1,"@"),(2,"#"),(3,"$"),(4,"£")]
df=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(L).toDF(["ID","VALUE"])
df.show()
```

But here it's throwing error

```
"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can not encode characters in position 66-67:ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know it's happening since £ is not a ascii character. I have tried converting the characters in list into utf-8 / unicode 
, but still I am getting above error.

What can be the possible resolution here.

Answer (score 0):

try this: you were just not passing column value as a list

```
L=[(1,"@"),(2,"#"),(3,"$"),(4,"£")]
df = sc.parallelize(L).toDF(["ID","value"]).show()
+---+-----+
| ID|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    @|
|  2|    #|
|  3|    $|
|  4|    £|
+---+-----+
```

here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Not providing columns in a list was a typo. But it's not the issue, I was running the code with column names in list only. Issue I am getting is because of encoding

Comment: Which version of spark are you using? because pyspark 2.4+  is working perfectly fine

Comment: I am getting the result as same as yours  above if I am running code in my personal hortonwork on-prem cluster. But in my work cluster which is an AWS EMR , I am getting the error which I have mentioned above. Don't know why